# Setting number of looping

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I have problem. I need functions in **tool.c** file to loop only number of times that are required. Like it stops after looping thru whole input. My teacher said I should pass second argument, but class finished and I don't know how it should look.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tools.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int count[256] = { 0 };
    int c;
    while ( (c=getchar())!=EOF ){
        count[c]++;
    }
    switch (argc > 1 && argv[1][1]) {
    case 'm': case 'M':
        mostOften(count);
        break;
    case 'l': case 'L':
        leastOften(count);
        break;
    default:
        mostOften(count);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**tools.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "tools.h"

void mostOften(int *s) {
    int j, a = 0;
    int max=0, cha;
    for(j=32; j<126; j++){
        if(s[j]>max) {
                max=s[j];
                cha=j;
        }
    a++;
    }
    printf("char %c: %d times\n", cha, max);
}

void leastOften(int *s) {
    int j, a = 0;
    int min=INT_MAX, cha;
    for(j=32; j<126; j++){
        if(s[j] && s[j]<=min) {
                min=s[j];
                cha=j;
        }
    a++;
    }
    printf("char %c: %d times\n", cha, min);
}
```

For example if I input

> paragraph

I want it to loop only 9 times, basically I need to set some if statment to stop looping

Comment: please keep `case 'm': case 'M':` in separate lines.

Comment: `switch (argc > 1 && argv[1][1]) {` should be `if(argc > 1) switch (argv[1][1]) {`

Comment: Please edit your question and show us an example of input and expected output.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Maybe something like this.

Comment: @zimek-atomek and what output do you expect ?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at how you have the problem setup, it looks like you are confusing iterating over the character that are part of the input, and the array that holds the frequency of the characters read.

For starters, to make your code readable, don't use magic numbers in your code, e.g. `32` and `126`. Instead use the characters you are attempting to represent, e.g.  (*space*) and `~` (*tilde*). For example, instead of using:

```
for(j=32; j<126; j++){
```

you could use:

```
for(j = ' '; j < '~'; j++){
```

That too has it's pitfalls. Why? You don't want to loop over characters, you actually want to loop over the elements in your `count` array that hold the frequency each character occurs in input. In other words, you need an array holding at minimum `95` integers which will hold the frequency each character occurs in your input. Since you know how may characters that will be, don't obscure it behind `32` to `126`, just declare a constant for your array size (maybe called `ARSZ`) in `tools.h`, e.g.

```
#define ARSZ 95
```

Then after reading your input and filling the `count` array, it is just a matter of iterating over the `count` array once to get either the `mostoften` or `leastoften` number. Further, since you have a constant for the number of elements in `count` you do NOT need to pass the size of `count` to `mostoften` and `leastoften` -- you already know how many elements are present, `95`. (see below for notes on iterating only over the characters present in input)

(if the array size is Not constant (and you are not passing an array with a sentinel like a *nul-terminated* string) or the number of elements you need to iterate over is not known at compile time, then you DO need to pass the size of the array to the functions.

(and another quick aside, C generally uses all lower-case for variable names, reserving all upper-case for constants and macros. You will not ordinarily see *MixedCase* or *camelCase* variable names in C, leave that for C++)

Next, while you should use `getopt` for processing command line arguments, you can use a quick hack of checking the second character of the arguments at issue, but you need to validate you have at least one argument to check and that the argument isn't an *empty-string*. Basically, you want to check:

```
if (argc > 1 && *argv[1])  /* check argc & not empty-string */
    switch (argv[1][1]) {
        case 'm':
            mostoften (count);
            break;
        case 'M':
            mostoften (count);
            break;
        case 'l':
            leastoften (count);
            break;
        case 'L':
            leastoften (count);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: unrecognized option, using 'mostoften'.\n");
            mostoften (count);
    }
else {
    fprintf (stderr, "warning: no option given using 'mostoften'.\n");
    mostoften (count);
}
```

*note*: you can't put two constant conditions together for any single case of your `switch` (some compilers provide non-standard extensions). Also note, you do not need a `break` in the `default` case, there is no fall-through possible.

Putting it altogether, you could write your `tools.h` similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define ARSZ 95

int mostoften (int *a);
int leastoften (int *a);
```

Your `tools.c` as:

```
#include "tools.h"

int mostoften (int *a) {

    int i, max = INT_MIN, cha = '0';

    for (i = 0; i < ARSZ; i++)
        if (a[i] > max) {
            max = a[i];
            cha = i + ' ';
        }

    printf ("char '%c' : %d times\n", cha, max);

    return max;
}

int leastoften (int *a) {

    int i, min = INT_MAX, cha = '0';

    for (i = 0; i < ARSZ; i++)
        if (a[i] < min) {
            min = a[i];
            cha = i + ' ';
        }

    printf ("char '%c' : %d times\n", cha, min);

    return min;
}
```

You do know that if the `max` or `min` is the same for 2 different characters, you will select the first, and in the case of `leastoften` you will always select the first character with `0` frequency. To correct this problem, you will need to keep a second array (or 2D array, or struct) that tracks which characters were present in the input and only consider the frequency for those characters.

Finally, your `main.c` could be written something like:

```
#include "tools.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int c = 0, count[ARSZ] = {0};

    while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF)
        if (' ' <= c && c <= '~')
            count[c - ' ']++;

    if (argc > 1 && *argv[1])  /* check argc & not empty-string */
        switch (argv[1][1]) {
            case 'm':
                mostoften (count);
                break;
            case 'M':
                mostoften (count);
                break;
            case 'l':
                leastoften (count);
                break;
            case 'L':
                leastoften (count);
                break;
            default:
                fprintf (stderr, "warning: unrecognized option, using "
                                 "'mostoften'.\n");
                mostoften (count);
        }
    else {
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: no option given using 'mostoften'.\n");
        mostoften (count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There are many different ways to accomplish this task, but given your initial code, this keeps with what appeared to be your intent. Look it over and let me know if you have any questions. If you want the easiest way to track the characters present in your input without using a struct, then simply declaring `count` as `count[ARSZ][2]` and using the additional element to indicate which characters were present would do. (you can pass the array to your functions as `int a[][2]` or `int (*a)[2]`) Good luck.